# Remove outliers based on a preceding value

Tags: r, outliers

How to remove outliers using a criterion that a value cannot be more than 2-fold higher then its preceding one.

Here is my try:

```
x<-c(1,2,6,4,10,20,50,10,2,1)

remove_outliers <- function(x, na.rm = TRUE, ...) {
  for(i in 1:length(x))
  x < (x[i-1] + 2*x)
  x
}

remove_outliers(y)
```

expected outcome: 1,2,4,10,20,2,1

Thanks!

Comment: What does 2-fold higher signify?

Comment: Yes, I mean:  x<2*x[i-1]

Comment: Can you write explicitly the formula? x<2*x[i-1]+...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the first 10 should be removed in your data because 10>2*4. Here's a way to do what you want without loops. I'm using the `dplyr` version of `lag`.

```
library(dplyr)
x<-c(1,2,6,4,10,20,50,10,2,1)
x[c(TRUE,na.omit(x<=dplyr::lag(x)*2))]
[1]  1  2  4 20 10  2  1
```

**EDIT**

To use this with a `data.frame`:

```
df <- data.frame(id=1:10, x=c(1,2,6,4,10,20,50,10,2,1))
df[c(TRUE,na.omit(df$x<=dplyr::lag(df$x,1)*2)),]

   id  x
1   1  1
2   2  2
4   4  4
6   6 20
8   8 10
9   9  2
10 10  1
```

Comment: Strange, I tried your code but I get this as a result : `[1]  1  2  6  4 10 20 50 10  2  1 NA`

Comment: @MbrMbr @AK88 Yeah, I have `dplyr` loaded so it's that version and not `stats`. It's a shame Hadley chose the exact same name for an important function like this. I also have a conflict with `filter`.

Comment: @PLapointe Yeah it's confusing to have two functions with the same name.

Comment: is there a simple way to use this solution directly on a dataframe, where x is column [2]

Answer (score 0):

A simple sapply:

```
bool<-sapply(seq_along(1:length(x)),function(i) {ifelse(x[i]<2*x[i-1],FALSE,TRUE)})

 bool
[[1]]
logical(0)

[[2]]
[1] TRUE

[[3]]
[1] TRUE

[[4]]
[1] FALSE

[[5]]
[1] TRUE

[[6]]
[1] TRUE

[[7]]
[1] TRUE

[[8]]
[1] FALSE

[[9]]
[1] FALSE

[[10]]
[1] FALSE
```

resulting in:

```
x[unlist(bool)]
[1]  1  2  4 10 20  1
```

Comment: the expected outcome should be: 
[1]  1  2  4 20 10  2  1